# Why does my Fractal Noise have lines outlining a grid

Tags: c, fractals, perlin-noise, noise-generator

[image]

I will give some context to the function that I wrote:
`getFractalPointHeight()` is a function that is supposed to return the height of the fractal noise based on the coordinates of a Perlin noise image and the other 2 values `amplitude` and `frequency`
To get the height from the perlin noise I use the function `getPointHeight()`.
The perlin noise is a grid of length `nodesxn - 1` * `nodesyn - 1`.

The four `while`s I wrote in the function are supposed to change the coordinates in case they are outside the perlin noise boundaries however it doesn't tile correctly as shown in the image above

```
float getFractalPointHeight(float x,float y,int octaves,float amplitude,float frequency){

    float elevation = amplitude;

    for(int i = 0;i<octaves;i++){

        float sx = x * frequency;
        float sy = y * frequency;

        while(sx < 0){
            sx = sx + (nodesxn - 1);
        }
        while(sy < 0){
            sy = sy + (nodesyn - 1);
        }
        while(sx > nodesxn - 1){
            sx = sx - (nodesxn - 1);
        }
        while(sy > nodesyn - 1){
            sy = sy - (nodesyn - 1);
        }

        elevation += getPointHeight(sx,sy) * amplitude;

        frequency *= 2;

        amplitude *= 0.5;

    }

    elevation = fmin(2,fmax(elevation,0));

    return elevation;
}
```

Comment: Rather than `while(sx < 0){ sx = sx + (nodesxn - 1); } ... while(sx > nodesxn - 1){ sx = sx - (nodesxn - 1); }`, consider `sx = fmodf(sx, nodesxn - 1); if (sx < 0){ sx = sx + (nodesxn - 1);`.  Likewise for `sy`.  The `while()` loop approach can incur much round off errors.

Comment: Please provide some sample data including the length of the box artifact.

Comment: Investigative idea: similar result when `double` used instead of `float`?

Comment: Aside: `fmin(2,fmax(elevation,0))` uses `double` functions.

Comment: I tried using fmod and switching from ``float`` to ``double`` but in both cases the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was: The perlin noise I generated wasn't seamless.
I made the vectors at the edges of the perlin noise grid identical and now the fractal noise looks fine